# What do we enter in the parameter field when we use "most trusted source" as the survivorship function (i.e., using t-swoosh algorithm in tMatchGroup)

Tags: talend

I would like to create a master record from customer listing in multiple sources (i.e., Golden Customer Record / Master Data Management) using a Talend job. Research indicates that the tMatchGroup is the best component to perform this as it is capable of merging records base on survivorship rules.

My question is, if I would like to use the "most trusted source" survivorship function, how do I list the source ranking in the parameter field when I use the t-swoosh algorithm? The documentation does not show how to do this and I can't find anything online.

[This](https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/7.3/data-matching/tmatchgroup) is the documentation I am referring to. Any advise would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer to this is you can't. This is for the MDM component of Talend which has reached EOL.